# Merging FB connect account & site account

Tags: facebook, merge

I have Facebook connect working along side my own site registration.
My question is can i merge an existing account with a Facebook account based on the email returned by Facebook?

Can i trust that the email Facebook returns to me is verified?

Answer (score 1):

Just to build on East of Nowhere's answer, if you do end up with a user who has two accounts, In Drupal, you can swap out theUID of the new FB account for the user's original account in the fb_user table. This will connect the facebook ID with the original account and you can then delete the new account that was created as a result of the email mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using their facebook id instead. You can enter whatever email you want into facebook, but each user only gets one unique ID.

Just add "facebook_id" to your user table and when they connect facebook to your site save that id in their user record.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a Facebook login button on your website that requires `email` permissions, the FB user can select any email they've associated with their FB account, *which may not be the same email address they used to create an account with your website.* If they're already logged in to your website with an existing account and then use the FB login button, you can connect the accounts like Tspesh said.

But the other scenario is an existing user isn't logged in and then goes to the website and uses the FB login. If they happen to provide the same email address as the existing website account, you're in luck and can still connect the two accounts. If they provide a different email, the user would end up with two separate site registrations so you'd need to provide them some way to merge the two, probably by prompting them to specifically enter their previous registration email address.